# raspberrypiでgattlibをmakeするときのエラー

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

https://qiita.com/utsuki_protein/items/5e66b53c55359efbec66
上のサイトを参考にraspberrypiにgattlibをインストールしようとしています．

対策②のほうでやっているのですが，https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib/downloads/
からzipファイルをダウンロードし，解凍した後にmakeを実行するとエラーが出てしまいます．どのようにすれば解決するでしょうか．
発生するエラーは以下の通りです．

```
bluez/btio/btio.c: In function ‘set_le_imtu’:
bluez/btio/btio.c:624:38: error: ‘BT_RCVMTU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_BLUETOOTH, BT_RCVMTU, &imtu,

bluez/btio/btio.c:624:38: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only oncefor each function it appears in
bluez/btio/btio.c: In function ‘l2cap_get’:
bluez/btio/btio.c:985:39: error: ‘BT_RCVMTU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_BLUETOOTH, BT_RCVMTU,

bluez/btio/btio.c:1090:40: error: ‘BT_SNDMTU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_BLUETOOTH, BT_SNDMTU,

<ビルトイン>: ターゲット 'btio.o' のレシピで失敗しました
make[1]: *** [btio.o] エラー 1
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/pi/OscarAcena-pygattlib-a858e8626a93/src' から出ます
Makefile:4: ターゲット 'all' のレシピで失敗しました
make: *** [all] エラー 2
```

Answer (score 1):

コンパイラのエラー

```
bluez/btio/btio.c:624:38: error: ‘BT_RCVMTU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

bluez/btio/btio.c で参照している BT_RCVMTU が宣言されていないというものです。
`BT_RCVMTU`, `BT_SNDMTU` は bluez/btio/btio.h にて宣言されていますが、Makefile にヘッダファイルのインクルードパスを追加してみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
CFLAGS += -Ibluez/btio
```